# CSS not applying to image in django

Tags: html, css, django

I am trying to create a django app in which i have inserted an image. But css rule is not applying on the image. Image is inside a div which is inside a section

html file code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="en">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Venkatesh Akhouri</title>

</head>
<body>
<div class="conatiner">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light">
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Skills</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Projects</a>
    </nav>
</div>

<section id="small-info">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md">
            <img class="my-img" src="{% static 'images/myImg2.jpg' %}" alt="no img">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md">
            <h3> some info</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
body
{
background-color: #cce6ff;
}

.nav-item
{

font-family: font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
color: black;
}

.col-md
{
float: left;
width 50%;
}

#small-info .col-md
{
    width: 10px;
    border-radius: 50px;
}
```

I know there is some foolish mistake here, but i am not able to identify.
I've also tried w/o any div but still not working.

Comment: `But css rule` which one? Please elaborate what is the expected behavior. There is no class for `image` or "my-img" in the demonstrated CSS code.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, Try my Code i dont know if works but try it and give me feedback i hope it works.

Here is my Answer.

Try this if not works try my Answer number two

```css
#small-info .row .col-md .my-img
{
    width: 10px;
    border-radius: 50px;
}
```

Answer Two :

```css
#small-info.row.col-md.my-img
{
    width: 10px;
    border-radius: 50px;
}
```